# How often does Power Nap check for updates or back up?

Tags: macos, power-nap

How often does Power Nap check for updates or back up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Mail, Contacts, Calendar, Reminders, Notes, Photo Stream, Find My Mac, and iCloud Documents are checked every hour.
- Time Machine backups are attempted hourly until a successful backup has been completed.
- Software Updates are checked daily.
- Mac App Store downloads are checked once a week.

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5394